# Remote Regstry access denied for non-admin user

Tags: c#, windows, registry, registrykey

I am trying to open remote registry key with a non admin user who has been given access to registry key on remote machine.

```
remoteKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, hostname);
```

I am getting

> Requested registry access is not allowed.
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
>          at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
>          at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name)
>          at RemoteRegistry.Program.Main(String[] args)

Is it possible to access HKLM hive to be accessed remotely from any other machine for non-admin user ? on the other hand for admin user it works fine.

All other hives are accessible the above line does not cause any exception.

Any pointers what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

By default, remote access to most parts of the registry is only available to administrators.  You can grant access to other users by changing permissions on the [winreg registry key](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959389.aspx).

There is also a group policy setting (under Computer Configuration - Windows Settings - Security Settings - Local Policies - Security Options - Network access) which allows remote access to particular registry keys to all authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

Check these levels:

1. Default domain security settings apply to all systems/users in the domain, Unless block inheritance etc. is being utilized
2. Default Domain control security settings - only apply to DCs
3. Local computer policy - is the setting on the local machine

Comment: Can non-admin user access the remote registry HKLM hive?